# Django Rest Framework : Access primary key of field in serializer.is_valid -> serializer.errors

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I need to access the PK/ID of a field in the  default Django error message.

I need this because I add/update multiple fields.

How can I display which piece of data failed ?

Here is a simple use case of my problem.
I got a simple model :

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And a basic serializer :

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('__all__')
```

Now, sometime, when adding a list of users with the following function, I get errors :

```
def add_users(data):
    serializer = UserSerializer(
        data=data, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
     else:
        for index in range(0, len(serializer.errors)):
           logger.error("Validation failed: {0}".format(serializer.errors[index]))
```

Errors are displayed by default like this :

> Validation failed: {'name': ['This field may not be null.']}
>
> Validation failed: {'name': ['This field may not be null.']}

But I have 100 different users in my list.

I would like to know the PK/id values of the ones who trigger the errors.
How can I do that ?

Comment: error text about empty `name` why you write about `different users`?

Comment: can you show your data detail?

Comment: I updated with an answer. You did not understand. I don't care about the error. It is normal to get errors sometimes. The is just an example. I had a problem about how these errors where displayed. I wanted the PK value in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very elegant solution.

I created a superclass to display errors the way I want. Then, all my serializers heritate from this one.

Here is the piece of code :

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework import serializers


class GenericModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def run_validation(self, data):
        try:
            valid = super().run_validation(data)
            return valid
        except ValidationError as e:
            # check if it's a list. This error is not linked to one piece of data.
            if data.__class__ is [].__class__:
                raise e
            primary_key_field_name = self.Meta.model._meta.pk.name
            raise ValidationError("Entity {0} : {1}. Caused by : {2}".format(primary_key_field_name, data[primary_key_field_name], e.detail))
```

Now, the error diplayed looks like that, with the entity primary key value :

```
rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: [["Entity id : 1. Caused by : {'name': ['This field may not be null.']}"], ["
Entity id : 2. Caused by : {'name': ['This field may not be null.']}"], {}]
```

**Details**

GenericModelSerializer, heritates from "rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer". Then override the "run_validation" method.

It catches exceptions and log them with more information.
It uses "meta" to get the primary_key field name and value.

When a serializer is initialized with "many=True", the "run_validation()" is called by Django Rest Framework on each elements.

And it also works when only one element is handled.

**Be aware**

when updating multiple fields, you should use bulk operations. In this example, for 100 entities, the ORM will trigger 100 calls to the database. Bulk operations are much more effective since they will only trigger one call.

Answer (score 3):

`serializer.save()` method saves single object. And the `many=True` in the serializer has nothing to do with in the write operation. If your data contains multiple user data, then try something like this

```
def add_users(data):
    users = []
    for user_data in data:
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        users.append(user)
    return Response(data=UserSerializer(users, many=True).data)
```